# Limited line style for differentiating curves in the plot

Tags: plotting, legending, style

Question 1
I have a plot which consists of six curves, and I wanted to differentiate these line without using any color. I the only option that I left with is to use different line style. After looking at the documentation I only come up with these three, but I have six curves? how to do this?

Question 2
Out of these six plots, bottom three curves I have to name as mode shapes, the upper three curves as non-dimensional frequency. And there is a no horizontal line crossing at y=0; how to fix this?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
s1 = {4.76592, 4.80264, 4.84021, 4.87866, 4.91803, 4.95834, 4.99961, 
   5.04189, 5.08519, 5.12956, 5.17503, 5.22163, 5.26941, 5.31839, 
   5.36862, 5.42013, 5.47298, 5.52719, 5.58282, 5.63992, 5.69852, 
   5.75867, 5.82042, 5.88383, 5.94893, 6.01577, 6.08441, 6.15488, 
   6.22724, 6.30151, 6.37773, 6.45593, 6.53613, 6.61831, 6.70246, 
   6.78854, 6.87645, 6.96606, 7.05715, 7.14942, 7.24241, 7.33546, 
   7.42764, 7.51761, 7.60347, 7.6826, 7.7515, 7.80584, 7.84099, 
   7.8532, 7.84099, 7.80584, 7.7515, 7.6826, 7.60347, 7.51761, 
   7.42764, 7.33546, 7.24241, 7.14942, 7.05715, 6.96606, 6.87645, 
   6.78854, 6.70246, 6.61831, 6.53613, 6.45593, 6.37773, 6.30151, 
   6.22724, 6.15488, 6.08441, 6.01577, 5.94893, 5.88383, 5.82042, 
   5.75867, 5.69852, 5.63992, 5.58282, 5.52719, 5.47298, 5.42013, 
   5.36862, 5.31839, 5.26941, 5.22163, 5.17503, 5.12956, 5.08519, 
   5.04189, 4.99961, 4.95834, 4.91803, 4.87866, 4.84021, 4.80264, 
   4.76592};

s2 = {7.91294, 7.97447, 8.03787, 8.10242, 8.17017, 8.23608, 8.30852, 
   8.38107, 8.45563, 8.53225, 8.61098, 8.69187, 8.77496, 8.8603, 
   8.94792, 9.03787, 9.13018, 9.22488, 9.32199, 9.42152, 9.52347, 
   9.62782, 9.7345, 9.84343, 9.95447, 10.0674, 10.1818, 10.2973, 
   10.4131, 10.528, 10.6403, 10.7472, 10.8444, 10.9251, 10.9794, 
   10.995, 10.9619, 10.8794, 10.7575, 10.6107, 10.4515, 10.2891, 
   10.1298, 9.97812, 9.83806, 9.71347, 9.60863, 9.52835, 9.47753, 
   9.46008, 9.47753, 9.52835, 9.60863, 9.71347, 9.83806, 9.97812, 
   10.1298, 10.2891, 10.4515, 10.6107, 10.7575, 10.8794, 10.9619, 
   10.995, 10.9794, 10.9251, 10.8444, 10.7472, 10.6403, 10.528, 
   10.4131, 10.2973, 10.1818, 10.0674, 9.95447, 9.84343, 9.7345, 
   9.62782, 9.52347, 9.42152, 9.32199, 9.22488, 9.13018, 9.03787, 
   8.94792, 8.8603, 8.77496, 8.69187, 8.61098, 8.53225, 8.45563, 
   8.38107, 8.30852, 8.23794, 8.17017, 8.10242, 8.03741, 7.97447, 
   7.91294};

s3 = {11.0794, 11.1662, 11.2555, 11.3489, 11.4432, 11.5415, 11.6428, 
   11.7471, 11.8545, 11.965, 12.0786, 12.1953, 12.3151, 12.4381, 
   12.5641, 12.6931, 12.825, 12.9595, 13.0965, 13.2354, 13.3757, 
   13.5164, 13.6558, 13.7914, 13.9186, 14.0295, 14.11, 14.1365, 
   14.0811, 13.9338, 13.7184, 13.4721, 13.2245, 12.9965, 12.8054, 
   12.6674, 12.5945, 12.5884, 12.6394, 12.7332, 12.8573, 13.0026, 
   13.1625, 13.3323, 13.5074, 13.6822, 13.8488, 13.9943, 14.0984, 
   14.1372, 14.0984, 13.9943, 13.8488, 13.6822, 13.5074, 13.3323, 
   13.1625, 13.0026, 12.8573, 12.7332, 12.6394, 12.5884, 12.5945, 
   12.6674, 12.8054, 12.9965, 13.2245, 13.4721, 13.7184, 13.9338, 
   14.0811, 14.1365, 14.11, 14.0295, 13.9186, 13.7914, 13.6558, 
   13.5164, 13.3757, 13.2354, 13.0965, 12.9595, 12.825, 12.6931, 
   12.5641, 12.4381, 12.3151, 12.1953, 12.0786, 11.965, 11.8545, 
   11.7471, 11.6428, 11.5415, 11.4432, 11.348, 11.2555, 11.1667, 
   11.0794};

z1 = Table[i, {i, 0.01, 0.99, 0.01}];
data1 = Transpose[{z1, s1}];
data2 = Transpose[{z1, s2}];
data3 = Transpose[{z1, s3}];
peaks1 = FindPeaks[s1];
peaks2 = FindPeaks[s2];
peaks3 = FindPeaks[s3];
mark1 = {{0.50, 7.8532}};
mark2 = {{0.36, 10.995}, {0.64, 10.995}};
mark3 = {{0.28, 14.1365}, {0.50, 14.1372}, {0.72, 14.1365}};

mark4 = {{0.50, 0}};
mark5 = {{0.36, 0}, {0.64, 0}};
mark6 = {{0.28, 0}, {0.50, 0}, {0.72, 0}};
p1 = ListPlot[data1, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004], Dashing[Tiny]}, 
   AxesStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All];
p2 = ListPlot[data2, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004], Dashing[Large]}, 
   AxesStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All];
p3 = ListPlot[data3, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004]}, AxesStyle -> Black, 
   PlotRange -> All];

p4 = Graphics[{Text[Style["\[EmptyUpTriangle]", 25], #] & /@ mark1}];
p5 = Graphics[{Text[Style["\[EmptyCircle]", 25], #] & /@ mark2}];
p6 = Graphics[{Text[Style["\[EmptySquare]", 25], #] & /@ mark3}];
p7 = Graphics[{Text[Style["\[EmptyUpTriangle]", 25], #] & /@ mark4}];
p8 = Graphics[{Text[Style["\[EmptyCircle]", 25], #] & /@ mark5}];
p9 = Graphics[{Text[Style["\[EmptySquare]", 25], #] & /@ mark6}];


L = 1;
beta1 = {4.7300, 7.8532, 10.9956, 14.1372};
modefunction = ((Cos[b*x2] - 
      Cosh[b*x2]) - (((Cos[b*L] - Cosh[b*L])/(Sin[b*L] - 
         Sinh[b*L]))*(Sin[b*x2] - Sinh[b*x2])));
m3 = modefunction /. b -> beta1[[2]];
m4 = modefunction /. b -> beta1[[3]];
m5 = modefunction /. b -> beta1[[4]];
p10 = Plot[m3, {x2, 0, L}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004], Dashing[Tiny]}, 
   AxesStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All];
p11 = Plot[m4, {x2, 0, L}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004], Dashing[Large]}, 
   AxesStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All];
p12 = Plot[m5, {x2, 0, L}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004]}, 
   AxesStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All];
fig = Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, 
   PlotRange -> All, AxesStyle -> Black, 
   Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, False}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Beam Length", "Non-dimensional \[Beta]", , 
     "Mode Shapes"}, PlotLabel -> None, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 40, GrayLevel[0]}];
fig = Style[fig, GraphicsBoxOptions -> {ImageSize -> 1000}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotTheme.html) as follows:

```
{if1, if2, if3} = Interpolation /@ {data1, data2, data3};  

Quiet@Plot[{ m3, m4, m5, if1[x2], if2[x2], if3[x2]}, {x2, 0, L}, 
   PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", AxesStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"m3", "m4", "m5", "data1", "data2", "data3"}], 
   ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
   GridLines -> {None, {0, 5}}, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashing[{}]], 
   FrameLabel -> {{StringPadLeft["Non-dimensional β", 60], 
      StringPadRight[ "Mode shapes", 70]}, {"Beam Length", None}}, 
   Epilog -> ListPlot[{data1, data2, data3}, MaxPlotPoints -> 30, 
      PlotStyle -> Black, PlotTheme -> {"OpenMarkers"}][[1]]]
```

[image]

Use `Epilog -> (First /@ {p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9})` to get

[image]

Comment: actually, I have marked some maximum points in my OP, where I have used the triangle, circle, and squares. Now the thing is even we have a limited number of markers right. How to mark these point differentely

Comment: I used your code, But I am getting some unnecessary horizontal line near 5. How to avoid this

Comment: @acoustics, use `Epilog -> (First /@ {p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9})` to add your markers, and use `GridLines -> {None, {0}}` to remove the horizontal line at 5.

Comment: when I put the eps file of this result in a paper which is in double column in latex, The line of the curve, are bit difficult to distinguish. can we put the legend inside  the plot horizontally on the top of the plot, so that I can get some extra space in latex

Comment: @acoustics, try `PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[LineLegend[{"m3", "m4", "m5", "data1", "data2", "data3"}, 
   LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}], Top]`

Comment: Same command I tried, but it is appearing at  some 6 cm above my actual  plot

Comment: @acoustics, replace `Top` with `Scaled[{.5, 1.}]` and add the option `PlotRangeClipping->False`.

Comment: The the moment I take the eps of the end result and called in latex, I feel the lines are difficult to differentiate, is there any ways to control the spacing of these line styles.  I feel like  preparing the plot for journal paper in Mathematica is bit difficult.

Comment: @acoustics, you may get better help if you  post the issue you are having with eps/latex conversion as a new question.